# If Leviticus 15:17 says Discharge is a sin for 1 day, does that mean masterbation is a sin for one day?

Tags: leviticus

I'm trying to understand how the bible defines sexual immorality when the old testament says masterbation is a sin for 1 day as unclean. But, in the New Testament is says all sexual immorality is sin.  How do we interpret these differences ?

Comment: "when the old testament says masterbation is a sin" - please cite the scripture that you are deriving this from.

Comment: The Bible never mentions masturbation.  This question is off topic and thus not suitable for this site.

Comment: @Marion Carter ... please don't feel unwelcome by people questioning your question ;-) Many people think the Bible does deal with the issue. And you did cite a text that is often understood as you did.

Comment: Leviticus 15:17 **doesn't** say that discharge is a sin! So the entire foundation of this question is misplaced.

Comment: One must recall that men have a discharge of semen for reasons in addition to masturbation.  Thus, Lev 15:17 is not specifically about masturbation - it is text about hygiene!!

Comment: You might be able to get this re-opened if you evaluate some of the presuppositions and ask more directly what the text in various verses means. And, be sure to list the passages you're referring to in the New Testament. Edit, then make sure you flag it for moderator attention and ask about re-opening it.

Answer (score 4):

Lev. 15 deals with purity laws, not morality. It's not dealing with masturbation per se, but emissions of semen generally, including wet dreams. The rabbis of the Talmudic era interpreted this passage to relate to sexual intercourse as well as nocturnal emissions etc. They had a lot to say about masturbation as well, but not in relation to the rules in Leviticus. Some of the rabbis even went so far as to say that "sperm-wasting" was a sin worthy of death or having one's hand severed. (Mishneh Torah, 21:18; Niddah 13a:1-2)

**So the short answer is that a man who had an emission of semen from masturbating was considered ritually unclean for one day, the same status as for married intercourse in Lev. 15:18. This rule did not deal with morality or sin.**

Comment: It is noteworthy that ritual uncleanness (טֻמְאָה) was also attributed to sexual intercourse (Lev. 15:18), menstruation (Lev. 15:19), and delivering a baby (Lev. 12:2; in fact, more uncleanness was attributed to delivering a female baby; cf. Lev. 12:5). Shall we say that sexual intercourse is a sin? Menstruation is a sin? Delivering a baby is a sin?